# sending rest request from ionic mobile app to backend without https/ssl

Tags: ionic-framework, https, cors

I'm trying to make http call from an ionic-angular android app to a simple php backend, I don't need to secure the backend-frontend exchange and I don't send anything secret so I don't need https nor ssl. testing the thing from the browser works just fine, but when I run the app from the smartphone, the android studio logcat keeps showing this error :

```
Line 1 - Msg: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://192.168.11.103/backend-php/backend.php'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

here is my backend code :

```
<?php

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Authorization");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    
    function processRequest() {
        $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $request_body = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);
        
        /*
        processing the request body and rendering the response
        */
    }


    processRequest();

?>
```

in the httpd.conf apache config file I added these two lines (LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so is also active) :

```
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

in the front app (ionic - angular - capacitor - android) :
AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
......
```

network_security_config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true"></domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

res/xml/config.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <preference name="Scheme" value="https" />
  <preference name="usesCleartextTraffic" value="true" />
  <preference name="MixedContentMode" value="compatibility" />
</widget>
```

in the angular service class :

```
    this.http.post<ResponseModel>(
      'http://192.168.11.103/backend-php/backend.php',
      {
        // some data
      }
    ).subscribe(
      (response)=>{
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
      }
    );
```

I expect my android app should receive the response from the backend but still can't. I'm I missing something ?